# R: Vectorise setting active fields in R6

Tags: r, vectorization, purrr, r6

I have a simple R6 object generator, with a get/set active binding:

```
myClass <- R6Class("myClass",
                   private = list(
                     ..status = TRUE
                   ),
                   active = list(
                     status = function(value) {
                       if (missing(value)) {
                         private$..status
                       } else private$..status <- value
                     }
                   )
)
```

I can create a list of objects, generated using `myClass`:

```
class_list <- map(1:10, ~ myClass$new())
```

I can get the `status` of each object in the list, using `purrr:: map`:

```
map(class_list, ~ .x$status)
```

But what if I want to set the `status` of all objects in `class_list`? I wanted to do this with `purrr:: walk`:

```
walk(class_list, ~ .x$status <- FALSE)
```

This throws an `Error: unexpected [symbol]...`, as does using `=`.

Can anyone offer a solution? Using `purrr` is preferable.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can wrap those assignments within the `{}` and return the original object (`.x`)

```
map(class_list, ~ {.x$status <- FALSE; .x})
```

Now, check the `status` again

```
map_lgl(class_list, ~ .x$status)
#[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: Brilliant, I have to wait to accept this, but I will. Thanks!